# GPIO basically not working on STM32401CCU6 Blackpill

Tags: stm32, embedded, arm, stm32cubemx

As a newbie I switched from Nucleo to Blackpill recently (STM32401CCU6 ) and after an overally good start I faced a wall.

It seems like GPIOs are... dead for some reason:

- HAL_GPIO_WritePin/TogglePin does not work at all. I'm unable to change outputs' state using the code. This applies to all ports.
- HAL_GPIO_ReadPin does not work (always reads low level)
- Forcing an output state via configuring code (setting them HIGH or LOW) works however but they still don't respond to commands in the code
- PB2 pin, when configured to input with pull-up shows only 2.35V voltage instead of 3.3V
- Timers seem to work - when the pin is configured as PWM it works properly
- Solving some mathematical calculations using variables works as well (I ran the debugger)

I'm using ST-Link/V2 from my Nucleo board and CubeIDE. I made sure to have picked a correct MCU in IDE.

**Is there any reason for such problems or did I just burned the board?** I do not recall causing any short circuit or applying an excessive voltage to any pin but You can never be sure. BTW - I've been powering the board from 5V (there is a voltage regulator onboard so it could not harm).

The code is pretty straight forward. Of course it used to work on my Blackpill just fine but it stopped yesterday for good.

```
int main(void)
{
 
  HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();


  MX_GPIO_Init();
 
  while (1)

  {    
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(test_Pin, GPIOB);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
   }
  
}
```

GPIO configuring code (generated via IDE):

```
void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, test_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);


  /*Configure GPIO pins : PBPin PBPin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = test_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

Comment: Your parameters to `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin()` are in the wrong order.  It should be `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, test_Pin);`.  Also, show the definition of `test_Pin`.

Comment: I refuse to believe that I made such a brainless mistake. GPIO work like charm again, thank You.

...except PB2 though. There is still only 2.36V when set to input with pull-up resistor. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please, show your GPIO and clock configuration if you're using CubeMX. I have a feeling your GPIO ports has no clock provided to them. It usually results in all unclocked registers always reading as all zeroes, including when you do "read pin".